# How to access ICP management console in ICP for Data environment?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-pak-for-data

Need to access ICP Management Console, how can that be accomplished in the ICP Data Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting following error while accessing the ICP management console:

"CWOAU0062E: The OAuth service provider could not redirect the request because the redirect URI was not valid. Contact your system administrator to resolve the problem."

If its the case, first add the virtual-ip in the /etc/hosts file on the local machine, from where you accessing the browser.

For example, if it's Windows platform update the 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' file with virtual-ip for ICP for Data.

Then try to access 'https://`<virtual-ip>`:8443'

-Sanjit

ibm-cloud-private-data
icp4d